# How to use AngularJS UI-router capture this URL with an optional parameter?

Tags: angularjs, regex, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm using AngularJD ui-router to capture my URL and send two parameters from that URL to my controller. Here are my requirements:

- The first parameter is a mandatory integer (`id`)
- The second parameter is an optional string (`slug`)
- The two parameters are separated by a `/`
- I want it to ignore any single trailing `/`

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
$stateProvider.state('mystate',
  {
    url: '/mystate/{id:int}{slug:(?:/[^/]+)?}',
    params: {
      slug: {value: null}
    },
    templateUrl: 'partials/mystate.html',
    controller: function($stateParams) {
      console.log('$stateParams.id=',$stateParams.id, ' $stateParams.slug=',$stateParams.slug);
    }
  }
```

For URL: `mystate/1` This correctly captures:

```
$stateParams.id=1, $stateParams.slug=null
```

For URL: `mystate/1/myslug` This captures the wrong value for `slug`:

```
$stateParams.id=1, $stateParams.slug=/asdad
```

For URL: `mystate/1/` This doesn't capture anything.

For URL: `mystate/1/myslug/` This doesn't capture anything.

How can I write this so that it captures all four of the aforementioned URLs properly but doesn't pass any of the `/`s to the controller?

Answer (score 2):

For optional trailing slash, you need to [set strict mode to false](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes) in a config block:

```
angular.module('yourModule').config(['$urlMatcherFactoryProvider', function($urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
  $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
}]);
```

For having optional parameters, there's a long discussion [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/108). At the end, they suggest using `squash`:

```
$stateProvider.state('mystate',
{
  url: '/mystate/{id:int}/:slug',
  params: {
    slug: {value: null, squash: true}
  },
  templateUrl: 'partials/mystate.html',
  controller: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
    console.log('$stateParams.id=',$stateParams.id, ' $stateParams.slug=',$stateParams.slug);
  }]
}
```

`squash` has good [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider), if you set it to true, it omits the parameter from URL when it has the default value.

Comment: Thanks!! Where do I insert the line for `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider`? When I inserted it right before the $stateProvider line, I got: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
ReferenceError: $urlMatcherFactoryProvider is not defined`

Comment: You'll need to inject it first into your config function

Comment: @SaqibAli BTW you should use array notation for dependencies if you uglify/minify your code for browsers, see my `controller:` edit.

Comment: the $urlMatcherFactoryProvider line seems to have no effect.  I put it on my app, like you instructed. The slug and the id are being captured... but ONLY if there is a trailing slash (in either case)

Comment: Did you make sure that line is executed by putting a console.log statement next to it?