# How to make AngularJS UI-router take, but ignore optional trailing backslash in URL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularJS's UI-router to do routing. 
Currently, I have this:

```
  $stateProvider.state('mystate',
    {
      url: '/mystate/{id:int}/:slug/',
      params: {
        slug: {value: null, squash: true}
      },
      templateUrl: 'partials/mystate.html',
      controller: 'MyStateCtrl'
    }
  );
```

The `id` and optional `slug` URL parameters are captured iff there is a trailing backslash. If there is no trailing backslash, this pattern is not even matched. I need it to match with or without the trailing backslash in all cases. How can I do that?

I was told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34575708/1742777) to attach the following config on my app:

```
.config(['$urlMatcherFactoryProvider', function($urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
      $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
    }
  ]
)
```

I did. But it still doesn't work without the trailing slashes. What should I do?

Comment: What if you removed the trailing slash from the pattern?

Comment: If you want an optional parameter, why don't you use query style parameters at the end of your route?  You could encode them if the value is more than a simple string.

Comment: Harper, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Route parameters in UI Router are optional by default. That is why a trailing slash is needed. I can think of two solution to avoid the trailing slash if someone doesn't want to use query parameter approach:

1. Setting up another route for the `parameterless` version.
2. Using non url route parameters: that is omit the parameter you want
   to be optional and declare it in `params` attribute but in that case
   the optional parameter won't appear in the URL.

A sample code:

```
$stateProvider
.state('mystate', {
  url: '/mystate/{id:int}',
  params: {
    slug: {value: null, squash: true}
  },
  templateUrl: 'partials/mystate.html',
  controller: 'MyStateCtrl'
})
```

Comment: Most of the time, we should focus on giving some explanation rather than posting a complete functional code. That is why my intention was to give an explanation rather than a code sample. the OP can easily pick yours one for better understanding if it helps